# How the classifying spaces of Cartan class AI and D is calculated?

Tags: group-theory, topology, topological-order, topological-insulators

The $AI$ class means that the systems with $T^{2}=1$ symmetry. Which means that we can write our Hamiltonian in a real gauge, such that its eigenvectors are real.

So we can write our flat band hamiltonian $Q(k)$ which has same eigenvectors, but with trivial eigenvalues as $Q(k)=O(k)\Lambda O ^{T}(k)$ where $O(k)\in O(n+m)$ and $\Lambda=\
 \begin{pmatrix}
  I_{m} & 0 \\
  0 & -I_{n}  \\
 \end{pmatrix}
$
But $O\in O(m)\times O(n)$ gives same $Q$ so we take the coset such that,

$Q(k)\in O(m+n)/[O(m) \times O(n)]$ .

$m$ and $n$ are the number of bands above and below the fermi level. And this answer agrees with literature.

Now let's calculate same for $D$ class.  $D$ class means we have particle-hole$(C)$ symmetry such that $C^{2}=1$. So $C$ is same as $T$ but it anti-commutes with our Hamiltonian, and $m=n$ should be satisfied. Apart from that it should imply same reality condition for our hamiltonian.

So we could be able to write $Q(k)$ as   $Q(k)=O(k)\Lambda O ^{T}(k)$ where $O(k)\in O(2n)$ and $\Lambda=\
 \begin{pmatrix}
  I_{n} & 0 \\
  0 & -I_{n}  \\
 \end{pmatrix}
$
But $O\in O(n)\times O(n)$ gives same $Q$ so we take the coset such that, $Q(k)\in O(2n)/[O(n) \times O(n)]$ .

But according to the literature, it is wrong, the answer is $Q(k)\in O(2n)/[U(n) ]$.
So what is wrong with my approach?